# Apriori vs Associative Mining

Tags: data-mining, apriori

This is less of a code question and more of a 'I need to wrap my head around this' question.

From what I know the Apriori mining algorithm falls under the category of associative mining, meaning it extracts information using rules based on relationships in the data.

When I do research on both of them they both appear strikingly similar, so what's the difference? Are they even different things? If so, what makes Apriori unique?

Comment: What is "Associative Mining"? Never heard that term.

Answer (score 1):

Associative Mining or Association Rule Mining is a hypernym of Apriori. The term Association Rule Mining refers to the description of extraction of association rules from data in general. The term Apriori refers to the Apriori Algorithm which is a specific mechanism to extract association rules from data. From an object oriented point of view you could see it like Association Rule Mining is the parent object of the Apriori Algorithm. It contains an abstract theoritical description of association rule mining. It knows what association rule mining is but is'nt able to perform it. And the Apriori Algorithm is the child object which inherits from the Association Rule Mining object. It does'nt only knows what association rule mining is but also it can actually do association rule mining. Same with for example the FP-Growth algorithm. Another algorithm to perform association rule mining. As the Apriori Algorithm the FP-Growth Algorithm belongs under the term Association Rule Mining. It'd inherit from the Association Rule Mining Object and stand side by side by the Apriori object.